# Firebase & Swift: Array does not insert correctly

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to insert "temp" to returnData in the order received from Firebase. However, the array appends all the items with an image toward the end of the array.

**Desired index result**: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

**Current index result**: [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8] <-- index 4 has an image, but gets inserted to the top

```
func retrievePost(schoolId: String, completionHandler:@escaping([[String: Any]])->Void) {
    var returnData = [[ String: Any]]()
    database.collection("Posts")
        .whereField("schoolId", isEqualTo: schoolId)
        .order(by: "timestamp")
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for documentd in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    var temp = documentd.data()
                    temp["docId"] = documentd.documentID
                    getUserThumbnail(userId: temp["ownerId"] as! String) { returnImage in
                        if(returnImage != "") {
                            AF.request(returnImage, method: .get).response { response in
                                switch response.result {
                                    case .success(let response):
                                        temp["userImage"] =  UIImage(data: response!)
                                        returnData.insert(temp, at: 0)
                                        if(returnData.count == querySnapshot!.documents.count) {
                                            completionHandler(returnData)
                                        }
                                    case .failure(let error):
                                        print("error--->",error)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if(returnImage == ""){
                            temp["userImage"] =  UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
                            returnData.insert(temp, at: 0)
                            if(returnData.count == querySnapshot!.documents.count) {
                                completionHandler(returnData)
                            }
                        }
                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alamofire request works asynchronously, it takes time and the data is returned later.

Try the `enumerated` syntax and insert the item at the given index

```
  for (index, documentd) in querySnapshot!.documents.enumerated() {
        var temp = documentd.data()
        temp["docId"] = documentd.documentID
        getUserThumbnail(userId: temp["ownerId"] as! String) { returnImage in
            if !returnImage.isEmpty {
                AF.request(returnImage, method: .get).response { response in
                    switch response.result {
                        case .success(let response):
                            temp["userImage"] =  UIImage(data: response!)
                            returnData.insert(temp, at: index)
                            if returnData.count == querySnapshot!.documents.count {
                                completionHandler(returnData)
                            }
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("error--->",error)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                temp["userImage"] =  UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
                returnData.insert(temp, at: 0)
                if returnData.count == querySnapshot!.documents.count {
                    completionHandler(returnData)
                }
            }
            
    }
```

A more reliable way is `DispatchGroup` or an asynchronous `Operation`

Note: Prefer the `if !returnImage.isEmpty` syntax, and `else if` is redundant. A `Bool` has only two values